# Canvas + Nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker, canvas, nestjs

I'm trying to install canvas on a nodejs project, but I'm getting installation errors

npm i canvas

Dockerfile seems to have been corrected according to the instructions, but the error is still there

[tutorial](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas)

get errors

```
    `/usr/src/app $ npm  i canvas
    npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! path /usr/src/app/node_modules/canvas
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --update-binary
    npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/usr/src/app/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/usr/src/app/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v111' (1)
    npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.10
    npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@19.4.0 | linux | arm64
    npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v111-linux-musl-arm64.tar.gz
    npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v111-linux-musl-arm64.tar.gz 
    npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.11.2 and node@19.4.0 (node-v111 ABI, musl) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
    npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v111-linux-musl-arm64.tar.gz
`
```

Dockerfile

```
`###################
# BUILD FOR LOCAL DEVELOPMENT
###################
FROM node:19.4-alpine3.16 As development

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -qq build-essential libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev librsvg2-dev

# Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
# A wildcard is used to ensure copying both package.json AND package-lock.json (when available).
# Copying this first prevents re-running npm install on every code change.
COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./
COPY --chown=node:node prisma ./prisma/

# Install app dependencies using the `npm ci` command instead of `npm install`
RUN npm ci

# Bundle app source
COPY --chown=node:node . .

# Use the node user from the image (instead of the root user)
USER node`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.